# Cakephp email component stopped working

Tags: email, cakephp, dreamhost

Yesterday I wrote code to automatically send emails upon receiving an IPN notification from paypal.  Everything worked great, and I spent the afternoon testing.  Today, everything still works except that no emails are being sent.  I recreated problem using the most basic code possible:

```
$this->Email->from    = 'Jiminy <Biminy@gmail.com>'; //fake email
$this->Email->to      = 'todd@xxxxxx.com'; //my email
$this->Email->subject = 'broken';
$this->Email->send('Test Send');
```

Using $this->Email->delivery = 'debug'; shows no problems, and I also attempted to use the native php mail() function to send a test email.  Did not work.

I am hosted on Dreamhost, and am working live through a sandbox subdomain created in the past week.  What could be going wrong in this case?  Should I be looking into it from a hosting side?  Any ideas?

thanks!
Todd

Comment: Problem is solved.  All emails came pouring in about 2 hours late.  Seems there was a delay of outgoing emails that was resolved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.  All emails came pouring in about 2 hours late.  Seems there was a problem on the delivery side, so no change in code was needed.